# how to use json.parse() method with external .json file stored in PC

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, parsing

[THIS IS WHAT IS APPEARING WHEN I CONSOLE.LOG(REQUEST)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Bz2.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKrDd.png)i have this json data --

[
{"10015022013": ["000202", "001661", "001860", "003555", "004251", "004386", "004453", "005657", "006004", "006031", "006387", "006436", "006980", "007311", "007714", "008511", "008874", "008886", "009328", "009344", "009345", "009441", "010344", "010400", "010604", "010998", "011547", "012863", "014522", "016587", "018854", "018883", "019104", "020207", "020685", "022857", "023938", "025331", "025663", "026968", "030152", "031049", "031186", "031284", "031307", "031700", "032152", "032395", "032857", "033128", "033898", "034465", "035796", "036561", "036760", "036798", "037548", "037658", "037778", "038579", "038928", "041549", "043528", "043838", "049691", "049903", "050439", "050530", "052013", "052617", "058264", "059085", "059179", "059533", "060207", "060860", "060984", "061709", "061843", "064000", "065105", "065190", "067506", "067710", "067872", "068904", "069508", "070478", "070968", "072563", "072814", "072868", "072879", "073300", "073959", "074039", "075607", "076370", "076388", "077997", "078331", "078606", "078647", "078733", "079426", "079436", "079924", "080014", "080118", "083618", "084694", "087210", "088248", "090731", "090856", "092351", "092551", "092776", "093597", "094012", "098474", "098993", "100403", "101782", "101881", "104025", "104535", "105518", "107051", "109444", "109868", "110345", "114280", "116405", "116537", "116927", "119034", "119645", "119976", "122512", "123751", "124471", "125726", "129951", "129988", "130825", "131949", "132142", "133328", "133382", "135095", "135678", "135709", "137387", "137857", "137891", "138385", "140242", "140394", "141571", "142164", "142559", "142745", "143065", "143673", "144081", "145792", "146401", "146816", "151501", "151657", "151917", "152114", "152528", "154648", "155867", "156408", "156700", "157213", "159572", "161924", "163777", "163820", "164309", "165117", "166358", "166583", "166782", "167261", "169605", "170485", "170603", "170900", "171808", "175032", "175360", "176020", "177018", "177763", "178075", "179047", "180507", "183235", "183586", "184307", "185203", "187426", "187768", "188396", "188699", "188705", "189731", "191856", "192184", "193139", "194454", "194936", "195489", "195817", "196619", "196871", "197437", "198475", "199098", "200730", "200919", "201408", "201491", "201506", "201518", "201708", "202626", "203779", "203848", "204781", "205519", "206412", "207232", "207635", "208363", "210800", "211379", "211604", "212050", "212118", "213895", "214562", "215531", "216401", "219786", "219913", "220011", "221220", "222349", "224023", "224050", "225628", "226179", "226871", "226945", "227850", "227985", "229281", "229300", "229325", "231531", "232365", "232745", "234090", "234126", "236394", "237403", "237463", "237475", "238474", "241012", "241681", "242446", "242719", "244753", "245797", "248044", "248883", "250032", "250186", "250353", "250458", "250579", "251414", "251599", "251813", "251852", "252138", "252595", "255029", "255092", "255618", "255776", "258548", "258747", "259403", "259593", "259658", "259790", "261014", "261121", "261944", "263603", "263781", "264526", "265323", "265745", "266054", "267059", "267093", "270746", "272673", "272993", "274319", "274802", "275552", "276960", "277463", "277571", "278220", "278648", "279387", "281877", "282318", "283118", "283475", "283741", "284376", "288210", "290043", "290747", "291112", "292056", "292077", "292566", "293470", "294232", "294601", "295535", "297258", "297759", "298325", "298704", "298750", "298982", "299154", "299725", "299897", "301293", "303179", "303548", "303994", "304562", "306731", "307810", "308132", "310767", "311068", "311201", "311343", "311577", "312963", "313257", "313300", "313859", "315679", "316596", "316711", "317545", "317831", "319378", "321260", "321358", "321488", "321833", "322751", "325099", "325183", "325385", "325944", "326083", "327190", "329927", "330322", "331577", "332119", "332289", "332360", "333117", "333808", "333974", "334611", "335803", "337193", "337995", "339131", "340739", "341963", "343279", "345213", "346106", "346612", "347911", "348331", "349076", "349717", "352136", "353738", "353907", "354989", "355784", "356106", "356729", "357716", "358531", "358667", "359510", "359543", "360304", "360584", "363146", "363720", "365470", "365485", "366293", "368721", "369546", "370543", "371623", "372333", "372937", "373547", "373617", "373897", "374338", "374814", "378799", "379725", "380468", "380813", "381370", "382023", "383389", "384139", "384964", "384979", "384994", "385106", "385110", "388046", "388091", "388960", "389170", "389833", "391221", "392003", "394063", "395199", "395389", "395731", "398350", "398502", "398853", "398906", "398996", "399285", "399974", "400320", "401351", "401666", "402107", "402343", "404106", "406321", "408274", "408844", "411255", "412104", "412907", "414207", "414468", "415382", "416168", "417546", "418235", "418241", "418508", "418902", "418968", "420245", "420353", "421057", "424321", "424705", "425350", "425591", "426209", "426621", "426908", "426913", "427065", "427455", "427520", "428409", "429678", "430478", "430721", "430990", "433074", "433605", "434048", "434601", "434936", "435023", "437398", "438385", "443009", "443377", "444101", "444107", "444611", "444899", "445148", "445722", "447532", "448071", "449249", "449518", "450208", "452814", "453627", "454843", "455386", "455393", "456701", "457225", "458380", "463570", "464883", "465908", "466803", "467281", "467673", "467895", "468726", "469050", "472241", "473106", "473448", "473807", "473848", "475209", "476043", "476484", "476701", "478101", "478610", "478796", "479685", "480428", "481916", "482302", "483013", "483744", "484024", "485265", "485397", "485495", "486316", "486519", "486530", "487306", "488137", "488989", "489009", "490533", "491944", "492056", "492298", "493380", "493619", "494446", "495187", "495604", "495969", "496533", "496817", "496963", "497930", "498950", "499202", "499656", "500389", "502592", "504131", "505260", "505505", "506095", "507730", "508102", "508825", "509248", "509804", "509824", "510475", "512615", "514955", "515743", "516339", "516913", "517757", "518062", "518574", "519839", "520012", "520716", "520824", "522108", "523200", "523308", "523523", "523596", "524019", "524092", "524451", "527617", "527623", "528099", "529812", "530176", "531258", "532776", "533591", "533780", "534105", "535917", "535994", "539473", "540099", "540535", "541511", "542429", "542787", "542948", "543014", "543145", "543150", "543648", "545567", "545663", "546284", "546288", "546591", "546804", "547097", "549895", "550986", "551256", "551526", "554174", "554866", "556099", "557349", "558078", "559498", "560255", "560448", "560731", "560812", "561891", "563325", "565009", "566064", "566538", "566578", "568114", "568435", "568652", "570385", "572432", "575738", "575891", "575952", "576128", "576184", "576350", "577495", "578315", "578787", "579084", "580368", "581225", "581752", "583048", "583620", "587825", "588866", "589672", "589807", "591629", "591884", "592912", "594019", "594938", "596784", "597705", "598608", "598913", "599241", "599527", "600367", "601326", "602233", "602701", "603208", "603887", "604764", "607259", "607412", "607871", "608131", "608593", "608710", "608776", "609346", "610087", "611125", "611459", "612456", "614613", "615214", "616594", "617013", "619352", "620372", "620689", "621656", "621891", "622035", "622144", "623347", "623458", "623648", "624046", "624342", "624455", "625615", "626397", "626621", "627534", "627668", "628644", "628856", "629823", "630683", "630805", "631516", "631744", "631807", "631882", "633362", "633744", "634042", "634049", "634387", "636331", "637779", "638861", "640193", "641472", "641979", "642224", "642332", "643851", "644618", "644795", "645343", "645992", "646306", "647753", "648267", "648281", "652737", "653142", "653190", "654004", "654726", "655501", "655862", "655892", "656645", "657473", "658164", "661198", "661260", "661374", "661512", "661711", "662932", "663555", "663652", "663773", "664243", "664586", "665270", "665858", "666203", "666700", "666970", "667436", "667442", "668589", "669131", "669509", "669932", "671471", "672686", "674361", "674698", "675542", "675749", "677042", "679545", "680333", "680918", "682730", "683603", "684420", "684617", "685548", "686958", "687161", "687886", "688619", "689434", "690158", "690961", "691312", "693020", "693148", "693382", "693511", "694714", "695333", "695376", "695939", "697939", "698605", "699627", "700159", "700257", "700762", "703818", "705153", "705223", "708962", "710317", "710598", "712628", "714182", "714206", "714640", "715095", "715987", "716068", "717060", "717352", "717591", "717737", "718577", "719934", "720601", "720743", "721575", "721877", "723049", "723274", "723922", "724360", "727040", "728059", "728320", "728748", "729709", "730598", "731060", "731479", "731518", "732389", "732936", "733663", "733706", "733810", "734070", "735572", "739474", "739504", "740323", "741767", "741896", "744291", "745667", "745875", "746639", "748048", "749044", "750167", "750623", "751504", "754458", "754873", "754907", "755593", "757610", "758470", "758639", "759636", "759687", "761282", "761855", "762050", "763043", "764498", "764881", "765030", "767106", "767626", "767662", "768979", "769322", "769521", "769630", "769791", "770378", "771413", "773258", "774814", "774826", "775013", "775496", "775857", "776004", "776264", "777370", "778444", "778654", "780515", "780568", "780759", "783616", "783747", "784121", "784126", "784881", "785462", "786504", "787035", "787372", "787477", "787994", "789134", "789914", "789938", "791359", "792170", "792963", "793374", "793403", "794505", "795423", "795864", "796303", "797338", "798519", "798666", "799027", "800325", "800531", "801793", "804127", "805648", "805737", "805777", "806061", "806812", "808553", "808595", "808912", "809512", "811491", "812742", "814110", "815398", "816435", "817541", "817616", "818847", "819802", "820362", "821325", "821709", "822360", "823677", "823813", "824125", "824862", "825708", "827385", "827610", "827980", "828419", "830550", "830847", "831591", "831987", "832258", "833395", "834267", "834877", "835103", "836019", "837511", "839060", "840971", "841157", "841733", "842002", "843539", "843900", "844937", "848767", "848830", "852245", "852612", "856197", "856288", "857970", "858264", "861853", "862011", "862776", "862957", "863102", "864267", "864417", "864929", "864959", "866936", "868514", "870047", "873271", "877112", "877460", "878134", "879265", "879483", "880301", "880904", "881169", "882409", "883255", "883917", "886263", "886525", "886672", "887353", "887622", "887752", "887963", "888500", "890086", "890392", "891865", "891936", "892224", "892265", "893116", "894328", "897715", "898286", "898891", "899648", "899943", "900098", "900735", "901290", "901993", "902276", "903088", "904952", "905585", "905761", "905844", "906397", "906961", "908318", "909822", "912397", "912432", "913430", "916773", "919786", "921076", "921578", "921762", "921963", "922277", "922686", "922734", "925006", "926364", "927171", "927236", "927341", "927901", "928157", "930182", "930357", "930637", "932851", "932945", "934194", "934277", "934394", "935317", "935779", "936281", "937878", "940398", "940823", "941853", "942035", "942062", "943027", "943533", "946066", "946474", "947464", "948780", "948835", "949665", "950512", "950661", "955751", "957629", "959212", "959386", "961285", "961623", "961630", "961798", "962532", "962753", "963934", "964882", "964975", "965397", "965450", "966428", "967666", "968345", "969581", "969807", "969836", "972125", "974424", "975165", "975424", "976076", "976380", "976570", "979445", "979780", "982055", "982556", "984155", "985402", "986204", "987345", "988349", "988674", "988777", "988913", "989587", "990555", "990929", "991575", "991596", "994732", "995112", "995945", "996490", "996987", "998147"]}

]

when i am parsing it so it can become an object

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET' , 'js/pb.json');
request.send();

let jsondata = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(jsondata);
```

it is showing this error in console.log

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at main.js:44

Comment: The error does not concern the data, but the result of the `XMLHttpRequest`. In other words: `request.responseText` probably contains an error message.

Comment: @KooiInc — No, it doesn't contain anything. It hasn't been populated yet.

Comment: I think `request.responseText` is already in `JSON` format not needed to be parse. You can directly use it as `JSON`. Example try to see what this return `request.responseText[0]["10015022013"]`.

Comment: Or first try to see what `console.log(request.responseText)` value that display before parsing.

Comment: @Sega it displays nothing :S

Comment: Then the data is not received you are trying to parse something empty or undefined.

Comment: Try @Quentin solution to see, it seems correct.

Comment: i only have the above data in a pb.json file.

Comment: when i console.log (request.responseText) it shows nothing , not even any error.

Comment: you can use `fetch` too. What is clear is that if the console.log(request.responseText) does not display anything that you are not fetching the data. Check again that `js/pb.json` is the good path to your `JSON`.

Comment: i am actually beginner and learning js , trying http request , will fetch work better than this ??

Comment: also i am sure the path is correct becuase earlier i was getting an error when the path was not correct.

Comment: What is clear is that if the console.log(request.responseText) does not display anything that you are not fetching the data. ---------------------- 

but when i console.log(request) it shows data in the dropdown request.response

Comment: so if I understood correctly what you said you should have `let jsondata = request.response` and not `let jsondata = request.responseText`?

Comment: when i console.log(request) it shows whole request 

but when i console.log(request.responseText) it shows nothing

this is what i am saying.

Comment: check the image which i added in the question .

Comment: @simpleguy1 — The console doesn't show a snapshot of the object, it shows the actual object. When the object is updated so is what is displayed in the console. You are looking at it in the console after the load event has fired. Just do what I told you to do in my answer from an hour ago.

Comment: Quentin I added an image after editing the question, this is what I am saying, I will try your method and will update here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

`XMLHttpRequest`, like pretty much everything that does i/o, in JS is asynchronous.

The value of `responseText` is **not** populated immediately.

You have to wait for the `load` event to trigger.

```
function loadEventHandler() {
    const json = this.responseText;
    console.log(json);
    const arrayFromJSON = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(arrayFromJSON);
}

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET' , 'js/pb.json');
request.addEventListener('load', loadEventHandler);
request.send();
```

Comment: @queintein thanks , i tried your method and it worked but i was not sure what i was doing wrong , the load event is triggered after the request is complete ,  but why my request was not complete ? why do i have to manullay traigger the load event ???

Comment: You don't have to trigger the load event. The load event is trigged when the content has been loaded. You have to provide a function to be called when that happens.